# Why I get "Disposed Exceptions" for "System.Data.SQLite.dll" in debug output?

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

While using the SQLite wrapper (version 1.0.109.2) in MS Visual Studio 2015, from time to time I get the following debug output message:

> Exception thrown: "System.ObjectDisposedException" in
>   System.Data.SQLite.dll

This actually is not generating any exception in my program. It continues to run.

Currently I am using the SQLite components within a single class which handles several data of the application. The SQLite interaction is capsuled in a private method which will be called through another method of this class.

What happens is this: When the code is executed, after approximated 50 executions (yes, I count it with help of a variable) of this method, 50 error messages are shown in the debug output window.

So following sample code will summarize my usage of the SQLite object. Right now it is pretty static.

```vb
Private Sub UpdateFoo()
  ' Create object variables
  Dim objSQLite as New System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" & sSQLitePath & ";Version=3")
  Dim objSQLiteCmd As New System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand(objSQLite)

  ' Do some magic stuff with the database ...

  ' Trash the command object.
  objSQLiteCmd.Dispose()

  ' Close DB connection and trash the SQLite object.
  objSQLite.Close()
  objSQLite.Dispose()
End Sub
```

So, what do I wrong? SQLite connection is closed before object will be disposed. This should be the right approach.

Comment: `Close()` and `Dispose()` do the same thing.

Comment: I'd recommend to use `Using` instead of manually disposing of your objects.  As it is, you could leak any unmanaged aspects of them in the event of an exception (which would bypass your manual disposal).

Comment: @SLaks Wow, thank you for the quick comment. I removed `objSQLite.Dispose()`without success. I still get those debug output messages.

Comment: @SLaks Really??? Are you referring to just Sqlite? I thought Close closed the connection to the database and Dispose released unmanaged resources.

Comment: You are setting your SQLiteCommand to its connection. Surely it should be SQL